# Concerning the uniqueness theorem and singular solution for first order higher degree ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

How to apply the uniqueness theorem for first order High degree ? we have to check whether F and Fy are continuous .. Is this check valid for higher degree ODE ? ...So do we have to try to put y' in one side of the equation to apply the check ? or instead we must get the envelope to check if we have singular solution ?

Comment: You shoul only ask one question at a time to increase chances for an answer.

Comment: What's "high degree" mean in this context? Perhaps you mean "dimension"? Or are you referring to issues with *implicit* ODEs of the form $F(x,y,y')=0$ where $F$ depends nonlinearly on $y'$? For the most part, if an implicit ODE has a solution, it can be locally converted into an explicit ODE using the implicit function theorem, and then you can locally apply whatever existence/uniqueness theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I edited the post .

Comment: if the first order derivative is squared  (second degree ) or has a power 3  ( third degree)

Comment: That's what I thought, but that's not the right way to think about it. You should be thinking about it the way I mentioned in my previous comment. Powers are not "special" as nonlinear functions go. The only significant thing is that odd powers are globally invertible while even powers are locally invertible away from zero.